# how to run YOLO NAS onnx weight file (custom.onnx)

Tags: yolo, onnx, nas, pth

In **YOLO NAS** i convert **best.pth** to **custom.onnx** but it can't execute the output

import torch
from super_gradients.training import models
from super_gradients.common.object_names import Models

model = models.get('yolo_nas_s', num_classes = 1,checkpoint_path ="best.pth")
img="3.jpg"

## It's work as well

model.predict(img).show()

## Here, i convert .pth to .onnx

models.convert_to_onnx(model=model,input_shape=(3,640,640),out_path="custom.onnx")

## after the conversion load the .onnx model

model = models.get('yolo_nas_s', num_classes = 1,checkpoint_path ="custom.onnx")

model.predict(img).show()

=============================================================
output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "yolo nas.py", line 8, in 
model =models.get("best.pth", num_classes = 1,checkpoint_path=model_path)
File "C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\envs\yolonas\lib\site-packages\super_gradients\training\models\model_factory.py", line 197, in get
net = instantiate_model(model_name, arch_params, checkpoint_num_classes, pretrained_weights, download_required_code)
File "C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\envs\yolonas\lib\site-packages\super_gradients\training\models\model_factory.py", line 103, in instantiate_model
architecture_cls, arch_params, pretrained_weights_path, is_remote = get_architecture(model_name, arch_params, download_required_code)
File "C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\envs\yolonas\lib\site-packages\super_gradients\training\models\model_factory.py", line 73, in get_architecture
raise UnknownTypeException(
super_gradients.common.exceptions.factory_exceptions.UnknownTypeException: The required model, "C:/Users/pc/Downloads/best.pth", was not found in SuperGradients. See docs or all_architectures.py for supported model names.